# FileOutputStream() not working?

Tags: java, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, fileoutputstream

I have this app. I'm working on. It allows users to view `JTable` instancess and at the same time have the option to save it in excel format or print it. It asks the user for the file name and location where to place the file then saves it in that location. The app is ran in the local server (tomcat), and it is used by other users in different workstations.  I'm using POI API in converting the table into an Excel file and it works well.

The problem now is that `FileOutputStream()` wont create any file at all for other workstations. It only creates/saves a file in a single workstation, the workstation where I am currently developing the app. I've searched long enough to find a solution, but I haven't found any yet so I'm trying to ask you guys for help. I'll be including the codes.

```
public class ReportToExcel
{
    //file returned comes from the user from antoher function.
    public void exportTable(JTable table, File file) throws IOException {
        HSSFWorkbook report = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet report_sheet = report.createSheet("report_sheet");
        HSSFRow rowHead = report_sheet.createRow((int)0);
        TableModel model = table.getModel();
        FileOutputStream reportOut = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("table to excel "+table.getName());

for(int x=0; x < model.getColumnCount(); x++) {
        rowHead.createCell((int)x).setCellValue(model.getColumnName(x));
        report_sheet.autoSizeColumn((int)x);
        System.out.println(x+". "+model.getColumnName(x));
    }

for(int i=1; i< model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            HSSFRow row = report_sheet.createRow((int)i);
            for(int j=0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                row.createCell((int)j).setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString());
                System.out.println(i+". "+model.getValueAt(i,j).toString());
            }
           }
       report.write(reportOut);
        reportOut.close();
        System.out.println("write out to: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void exportTable(JTable table, File file)`  It did not occur to you that the details of the `file` might be relevant?!?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The app is ran in the local server (tomcat) ? Is this server on your workstation ?

Comment: sorry im new here in stackoverflow i only know a little of your protocols, ill make a smaller version of the app.

Comment: Nope, the server isnt ran on my workstation. It has its own dedicated server

Comment: Please post the exception and stack trace. It almost certainly contains all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

Already found the answer. For NoClassDefFound error, the workstations need to have priveleges in accessing the classpath of the POI api which i definiteley overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I think a key statement from you is that the code only works on your workstation. Many times the issue is related to file/directory permissions. Normal users do have less permission than a developer.

Also helps if you tell us the output to file.getAbsolutePath() in case the path is suspicious.

The path should be a safe place for your users to create/modify files.

Comment: here's the output on the local machine where this app is being developed C:\Documents and Settings\exampleUser\Desktop and for Active Directory(AD) users \\pcName\\DepartMent\\Division\System\Team\ADuserName\Desktop  NOTE: using my AD username or anyone else's AD username on the same workstation where the app was built still saves/creates the excel file.

Comment: Perhaps a directory or subdirectory does not exist. Pls place try/catch exception handling to catch the error. I suspect you got file I/O error.  If you add enough System.out in your code, you probably will find out the exact problem. But add try/catch first, and run it on the problematic PC.

Comment: You were right, a part of the problem was due to I/O errors. Looks like i'm gonna ask the admin to set privileges. As for the other part, POI api doesn't seem to work on other workstations. it gives a NoClassDefFound error. Any solutions how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the output to the server, rather than the local machine for each workstation?

Comment: I'm not the administrator of the server where this app resides, i'm not allowed to install anything on the server even Java so i cant test it in the server.